# SQL (Oracle) use two defined list in where-statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to create a query where I use two pre-defines lists with multiple values as filters in a where-stakement. This so I can re-use the query easily for many value-pairs en for many value-pairs.

On Stackoverflow i found:

```
    WITH MyListOfValues(col1) AS (
  select 'MyValue1' from dual union
  select 'MyValue2' from dual union
  select 'MyValue3' from dual 
)
SELECT * 
FROM DatabaseTable  
WHERE Column in (
  select col1
  from  MyListOfValues);
```

Howerver it fails when i do something like:

```
    WITH MyListOfValues1(col1) AS (
          select 'MyValue1' from dual union
          select 'MyValue2' from dual union
          select 'MyValue3' from dual 
        )
    AND
    WITH MyListOfValues2(col1) AS (
          select 'MyValue1' from dual union
          select 'MyValue2' from dual union
          select 'MyValue3' from dual 
        )
        SELECT * 
        FROM DatabaseTable  
        WHERE Column1 in (
          select col1
          from  MyListOfValues1)
        AND Column2 in (
          select col1
          from  MyListOfValues2);
```

Does anyone has a solution?:) I'm doing this in a siting corporate enviroment I do not have rights (so far i know) to create my own tables.

Hope you can help me out! All help would be mutch appreciated:-)

Comment: What do you mean by **FAIL**? Error message or empty result?

Comment: Your `AND WITH` should simply be a comma. Also, you can use `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION` here - the values are already distinct.

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error.  The correct syntax for CTEs is:

```
WITH MyListOfValues1(col1) AS (
          select 'MyValue1' from dual union
          select 'MyValue2' from dual union
          select 'MyValue3' from dual 
        ),
     MyListOfValues2(col1) AS (
          select 'MyValue1' from dual union
          select 'MyValue2' from dual union
          select 'MyValue3' from dual 
        )
SELECT * 
FROM DatabaseTable  
WHERE Column1 in (select col1 from  MyListOfValues1) AND
      Column2 in (select col1 from  MyListOfValues2);
```

Comment: Thanks! This works. I figures there was something wrong with "AND WITH" in my first go above, but are unexperienced to guess the right solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `exits` instead

```
WITH MyListOfValues1(col1) AS (
          select 'MyValue1' from dual union
          select 'MyValue2' from dual union
          select 'MyValue3' from dual 
        ),
     MyListOfValues2(col1) AS (
          select 'MyValue1' from dual union
          select 'MyValue2' from dual union
          select 'MyValue3' from dual 
        )
SELECT * 
FROM DatabaseTable dt  
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM MyListOfValues1 WHERE col1 = dt.Column1) AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM MyListOfValues2 WHERE col1 = dt.Column2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a collection and the `MEMBER OF` operator

`SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST` is a built in `VARRAY` you can use:

```
SELECT * 
FROM DatabaseTable  
WHERE Column1 MEMBER OF SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST( 'MyValue1', 'MyValue2', 'MyValue3' )
AND   Column2 MEMBER OF SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST( 'MyValue1', 'MyValue2', 'MyValue3' );
```

Or you can define your own collection:

```
CREATE TYPE StringList IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(20);

SELECT * 
FROM DatabaseTable  
WHERE Column1 MEMBER OF StringList( 'MyValue1', 'MyValue2', 'MyValue3' )
AND   Column2 MEMBER OF StringList( 'MyValue1', 'MyValue2', 'MyValue3' );
```

You can even pass the collections as bind variables:

```
SELECT * 
FROM DatabaseTable  
WHERE Column1 MEMBER OF :List1
AND   Column2 MEMBER OF :List2;
```